# After adding @ManyToOne, result of findAll() is nothing (Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

- Entity:

product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufactoryID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private manufactory manufactory;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "quality")
    private String quality;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "discount")
    private int discount;

    @Column(name = "buyed")
    private int buyed;

    @Column(name = "viewed")
    private int viewed;

    @Column(name = "rated_total")
    private int rated_total;

    @Column(name = "rated_count")
    private int rated_count;

    @Column(name = "created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date created;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product"
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<productImages> productImages;
}
```

category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Getter
@Setter
public class category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // 1 category -> N products
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category" /* tên property category trong class product */
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<product> products;
}
```

manufactory

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manufactory")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class manufactory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    // 1 category -> N products
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "manufactory" /* tên property manufactory trong class product */
            , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<product> products;
}
```

- productRepo

```
@Repository
public interface productRepo extends JpaRepository<product, Integer> {

}
```

- productService

```
@Service
public interface productService {
    public product addProduct(product product);
    public product getProductByID(Integer ID);
    public List<product> getProduct();
    public void deleteProduct(Integer ID);
    public product updateProduct(product product);
}
```

- productServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class productServiceImpl implements productService {

    @Autowired
    private productRepo productRepo;

    @Override
    public List<product> getProduct() {
        return productRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

- productController

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private productService productService;

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<product> getProducts() {
        return productService.getProduct();
    }
}
```

So when i try to run it and test in Postman to see the result, it shows nothing like this
[Postman test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNHj7.png). Ofcourse in my database have records
I also tried to do something else like add this in productRepo

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.name, p.quality, p.price FROM product p " +
        "LEFT JOIN manufactory m ON p.manufactoryID = m.ID " +
        "LEFT JOIN category c ON p.categoryID=c.ID", nativeQuery=true)
List<product> getAllProducts();
```

Or add EntityManager in productServiceImpl

```
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM manufactory WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, manufactory.class);
        return query.getResultList();
```

It always informs me that there is an error somewhere.

I'm doing graduation thesis, and i'm new in Spring boot. Sorry if my English was so bad! English is not my mother language, and i'm really need some help

Comment: So before adding `@ManyToOne`you've got results? Another question: why do you name your product class lowercase? That's an absolutely nogo in Java by convention.